# How do you build SQL in Javsacript with single quotes inside string literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am building a SQL query in Javascript. I am passing values and what I want is if something is undefined then it needs to pass `null`. Here's is what it looks like:

```
const sql = `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(
  COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2
)
VALUES(
  ${param.value1 ?? null},
  ${param.value2 ?? null}
)`;
```

So, the null check works but when the value is defined the DB rejects it because the value is not wrapped within single quotes. For eg:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(
  COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2
)
VALUES(
  test,
  null
)
```

The DB expects me to enclode `test` within single quotes like `'test'`. But I am having a hard time figuring out an easy way to do this. How can I wrap my values in single quote if they are not undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: Please learn from [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) and don't compose SQL queries that way.  HINT: it's open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1):

add the quotes outside of the ${}, so '${}'

I could see this causing issues because you don't want 'null' to be specified, you want it to be null

Is it possible to change your query into a function with switch?  How many columns are you trying to populate?
you show two here, are there more?

```js
let param = {
  value1: 'test'
}
let sql = `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(
  COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2
)
VALUES(
  '${param.value1 ?? null}',
  '${param.value2 ?? null}'
)`;
console.log(sql);

sql = sql.replaceAll("'null'", "null");

console.log(sql);
```

Comment: I have 31 columns to fill with only one as non-null. Your solution will lead the SQL to output `'null'` instead of `null`. This will cause problems because some of the columns are too short to store `'null'`

Comment: fair. you could then run a string replace against it, replacing 'null' with null - alternatively use a framework to build your queries https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#insert